# How to access parent object when building an object through nested syntax in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, paperclip

I'm facing the current issue. I have a Paperclip processor that needs to access its existing parent object attributes when using the nested syntax `parent.children.create(file: File)`. I know I can use

```rb
child = parent.children.new
child.file = file
child.save
```

and this way have access to the parent, but since I'm in a big project and have `parent.children.create` all over the project it would be better if I could find a solution for the original problem.

My parser:

```rb
class Paperclip::Processors::ChildFileParser < ::Paperclip::Processor
  def make
    if @attachment.instance.parent.parent_attribute
      begin
        some_logic
      rescue => e
        Rails.logger.error("error")
      end
    end
    Paperclip::TempfileFactory.new.generate
  end
end
```

So when trying to access `@attachment.instance.parent.parent_attribute` in the `if` statement it will give an error `there is no parent_attribute for nil`. The above method is executed when building the child object.

Edit 1:

Just adding the relationship.

```rb
class Parent
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Child'
end

class Child
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you're after, though working with the code given this will avoid the `NoMethodError`s you're facing. If the parent does exist, you should be able to access it from the child even when using `build` / `create`. E.G.

```
c = parent.build_child
c.parent # => #<Parent id: ...>
```

Therefore, how about one of the following:

```
 # ref https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try
if @attachment.instance.parent.try(:parent_attribute)
  ...
end

# ref https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Safe+navigation+operator
if @attachment.instance.parent&.parent_attribute 
  ...
end

# both use safe navigation operators and are essentially short hand for:
# @attachment.instance.parent && @attachment.instance.parent.parent_attribute
```

These will return `nil` if there's not a parent, and so be falsey in order to step to `Paperclip::TempfileFactory.new.generate`.

You could also use [`delegate`](https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate):

```
# child.rb
delegate :parent_attribute, to: :parent, allow_nil: true
```

This would allow you to safely call:

```
if @attachment.instance.parent_attribute
  # ...
end
```

N.B. you can also provide a prefix to delegate if it helps clarify things when calling the method on `@attachment.instance`.

Hope that helps - let me know how you get on or if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks, @SRack, this actually was my temporary solution. But since I know the parent and the attribute exists in the database and is correctly instantiated when calling the `create` method, it should execute the `if` block. The problem is accessing the parent that doesn't seem possible. I think the way to go here will be just to save the child and use `DelayedJobs` gem to process it in the background.